# PyQT OSX Media Keys

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm creating a music player app with PyQT and I've defined a couple them as toolbar buttons. I can easily set the shortcut with setShortcut, but how can I set them to the OS X Media Keys? I already have iTunes disabled on launch so that's no problem. The music player Clementine has them also working when the application is not in focus, how can I have "global" hotkeys?

Many thanks!

Dennis

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
QKeySequence(Qt.Key_MediaPlay)
```

and others from http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html ?

Comment: Hi Kradem, I tried this but it didn't work for me. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, can you check?

Answer (score 1):

You only get global hot keys when you use the OSX native methods which seemingly change every minor release. An older example of this (i.e. doesn't work in Lion AFAIK) is available in libQxt

https://bitbucket.org/libqxt/libqxt/src/956e213e4f2d/src/gui/qxtglobalshortcut_mac.cpp

Comment: Thanks! It's definitely possible in Lion, I'm using Clementine which is a QT app for OSX, and works with global hotkeys.

Comment: For what its worth, I dug around and found an app I wrote that uses Control-Alt-Delete to trigger the screen saver on OSX and verified that it compiles/works on Lion without any problems. This doesn't solve your problem perse, but you wrap the code with Python or use it as a search aid to find implementations that might use similar methods for Python already. https://github.com/synthesizerpatel/lockscreen