# Cross-platform multimedia keys in Python

Tags: python, keyboard, cross-platform

I'm just starting on an application that will need to be able to receive multimedia key (play/pause, skip, previous) presses. I'm looking to target Mac, Linux (major distros), and Windows. I've seen [a solution for GNOME](http://www.bluesock.org/~willg/blog/dev/gnome_media_keys.html) that appears to do what I need, but as simple as it sounds, never anything that can pick up those keys on all major platforms. I also need to be able to pick up the keys globally, since the application will run in the background and won't ever have focus.

Currently, I'm not strongly tied to Python, but since I'd like to be able to target multiple platforms, Python seemed like the way to go. Has anyone written any cross-platform libraries that can do this? I haven't been able to find any that work.

PyQT looks like a potentially viable option, but [some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535867/pyqt-osx-media-keys) have hinted that global key detection may be problematic on OSX.

Comment: I don't want to be negative -- but I doubt you are easily going to find a multi-platform solution. Many platforms don't even have play/pause keys.

Comment: I'm aware of that. Obviously, I'm only targeting users who *have* those keys. Assuming I go with Python, I expect it would require a library of some kind to handle all the platform differences (rather than coding up support for each platform by hand). I saw some game libraries that came close (and were cross-platform), but couldn't detect keys globally.

Comment: OS X global access requires that the access for assistive devices is enabled. See https://github.com/mjpieters/quodlibet_plugins/blob/master/events/osxmmkey.py for some Python code that accesses the media keys (in a separate process because an event loop is required and that interfered with Quod Libet, the program this plugin was written for).

Answer (score 0):

With [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro) (or [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide)) you can use the `Qt::AA_CaptureMultimediaKeys` application flag to enable cross-platform capturing of multimedia keys. In principle, using that flag your Qt program should be able to receive keyboard events when the user presses multimedia keys such as Play (`Qt::Key_MediaPlay`), Stop (`Qt::Key_MediaStop`), Pause (`Qt::Key_MediaPause`) etc. For a full list of supported keys, have a look [at the documentation](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qt.html).

I cannot say if all keys will be supported on all platforms, but in general Qt aims to provide very good interoperability between different operating systems. I think with a simple prototype you should be able to answer that question really quick (I don't have access to a MacOS environment so I cannot test it there, but for Windows & Linux it should work). For more information on how to process keyboard events using Qt, have a look at the documentation of the [QKeyEvent class](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qkeyevent.html).

Answer (score 0):

I took over [python-mmkeys](http://codingteam.net/project/mmkeys-f/doc) a few months ago. I actually never tried to compile it, but it was included in the code of a project.

It is PyGTK dependant, but it is available on GNU/Linux, MacOX, and Windows.

The code is pretty easy to use:

```
import mmkeys
keys = mmkeys.Mmkeys()
keys.connect("mm_prev", previous_cb)
keys.connect("mm_next", next_cb)
keys.connect("mm_playpause", playpause_cb)
```

Comment: This looks tempting, but I can't get it to compile. The install script complains `fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory` even though I have python-dev installed. Any pointers?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about C. You can try with the [debian package](http://packages.debian.org/sid/python-mmkeys)

Comment: @Paco I was able to install the module from the repo, but even after correcting `keys = mmkeys.Mmkeys()` to `keys = mmkeys.MmKeys()`, I get the error `Error grabbing key 173, 0xa0c2818` 5 times (once for each supported key?); different key codes, same hex code. Running as root didn't help.

Comment: I didn't write the code for it, but here's [an example](https://gitorious.org/sonata/sonata/source/62768d0cbbb918978c7e84ab840aed632e75b6f0:sonata/main.py#L743)